# "Electro" radio voice - how do I do this?

Tags: effects, vocals

At the start of [this song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ceiFpCyv9gI), there's a voice which sounds really awesome. How do I make this effect? And what is this effect called?

Comment: The percussive vocal(ish) sample that goes "ay" (kind of)? or the bbc radio promo voice?

Comment: I have no idea to which voice you are referring. Time please?

Answer (score 0):

The proverbial 'radio' voice like the one in that song has its low frequencies removed. That is, run it through a high-pass filter. The break frequency is typically about several hundred Hz. Experiment for desired results.